# Calculate Correlation Coefficient Between 2 Variables Grouped by a 3rd Variable

Tags: r, excel, correlation

I have an excel spreadsheet with 3 columns. The first column is the id of a picture which groups the data together, and the 2nd and 3rd columns are the values I am trying to find a correlation coefficient for.

For example:

```
ID  Dat1 Dat2
130 4   4.3
130 7.5 5
130 6.6 6
180 5.6 
180 5   8.7
180 7.1 5
```

In that example, the data is grouped by the values in the 1st column and then they have separate data in the 2nd and 3rd columns. I'm not sure whether it would be easier to find the correlation coefficients for each grouping using excel or R.

I have tried the Data Analysis add-in in Excel but it won't work for 3 columns.

Thanks in advance!

The real data has hundreds of thousands of lines of data. This is just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using `data.table`

```
# install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[,cor(Dat1,Dat2),by="ID"]
```

Comment: So if I have, say, 4 groups of data in the 1st column will that give me 4 correlation coefficients?

Comment: Yes, if there are no `NAs`. If there are missing values try `df[,cor(Dat1,Dat2,use= "na.or.complete"),by="ID"]` (@akrun solution).

Comment: by the way, what is df?

Comment: data frame (your dataset).

Comment: thanks so much!! just one more question: when I get the coefficients, it goes from the 5th coefficient to the 697th coefficient with a --- in between. does it just skip the values in between since there's too much data? how do i get ALL of the data displayed?

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(df)`. `---` is data.table feature, it just shows head and tail.

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(Cor= cor(Dat1, Dat2, use= "na.or.complete"))
#   ID        Cor
#1 130  0.6407453
#2 180 -1.0000000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(130L, 130L, 130L, 180L, 180L, 180L),
Dat1 = c(4, 
7.5, 6.6, 5.6, 5, 7.1), Dat2 = c(4.3, 5, 6, NA, 8.7, 5)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Dat1", "Dat2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Two base R solutions, using @akrun's data:

```
with(df1, by(cbind(Dat1, Dat2), ID, cor, use = "complete"))
# INDICES: 130
#           Dat1      Dat2
# Dat1 1.0000000 0.6407453
# Dat2 0.6407453 1.0000000
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# INDICES: 180
#      Dat1 Dat2
# Dat1    1   -1
# Dat2   -1    1

lapply(split(df1, df1$ID), function(x) cor(x$Dat1, x$Dat2, use = "complete"))
# $`130`
# [1] 0.6407453
# 
# $`180`
# [1] -1
```

Comment: The first solution can be also `sapply(with(df1, by(df1[-1], df1[1], cor, use = "complete")),'[',2)`